# Restlet XStream/Jackson different JSON wrapper

Tags: json, annotations, jackson, restlet, xstream

I would like to switch from Xstream to Jackson for serializing/deserializing objects in a Restlet server. If i use Xstream libraries for:

```
@Get("json")
public Profile retrieve() {

    Profile prf = new Profile (...);

    ...

    return prf;
}
```

i would get something like:

```
{"Profile":{"id": 1, "name": "jack" ... }}
```

while with Jackson i get only:

```
{"id": 1, "name": "jack" ... }
```

How can i get the same JSON with Jackson? i would need this for KVC objects in my client (otherwise i need to specify the mappings manually)

I have the same issue if i return an ArrayList< Profile > , jackson doesn't wrap the list of Profiles when serialized and the JSON instead of

```
{Profile:[{firstProfile}, {secondProfile}]}
```

it looks like:

```
[{firstProfile}, {secondProfile}]
```

i've also been also trying to use Jackson annotations:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
public class MyProfileServerResource extends ServerResource {
```

but it seems it's not interpreted by restlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct place for the annotation is in the Profile class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
public class Profile extends Element implements Serializable {
```

and the json now looks like:

```
{"Profile":{ ... }}
```

and the return type is a Sub-classed list:

```
public class ProfileList extends ArrayList<Profile>
{}
```

see http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization 5.1